# Rails redirect_to in controller to correct page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several models with `has_many :attachments`.

I'm trying to redirect back to the `Note view` after the `Note` is created.

This is the attachments controller code I'm trying. The `@note` tells me that this attachment is related to that `Note`.

```
# GET /attachments/new
# GET /attachments/new.json
def new
  @attachment = Attachment.new
  @comment = params[:comment_id]
  @note = params[:note_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @attachment }
  end
end

# POST /attachments
# POST /attachments.json
def create
  @attachment = Attachment.new(params[:attachment])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @attachment.save
      if @note != nil
        format.html { redirect_to note_path(@note), notice: 'Attachment was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to attachments_path, notice: 'Attachment was successfully created.' }
      end
```

But, @note is nil by the time the `create` code happens.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you cannot access the instance variables initialized in new action in create. create is a separate http request which does not know anything about the instance variable @note

Comment: Is there some way to store the @note value in a global variable and use in the create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, you probably won't see "new" and "create" blocks executed in the same context. That's a bit of a mouthful, so lets be a bit more specific: the variables you declare in "new" won't still exist when "create" is called. So, any variables you want to use in "create" must be declared there as well.

One thing you can do (depending on the code) is share a block between different controller methods that initialized these variables for you. For example:

```
before_filter :initialize_vars, only: [:new, :create]
...
def initialize_vars
  @note = params[:note_id]
end
```

The "before_filter" will execute the "initialize_vars" method before any new request is sent to the "new" or "create" methods.

---

More generally, this relates to a pretty important Rails concept (and server-side web engineering in general) - that there is very little "state" within the server. The server takes a request, processes it, and forgets about it. Everything that's needs to be remembered must be stored in the server, or somehow communicated by the request the user sends.

Comment: I'm getting `Couldn't find Note without an ID' on the `@note = Note.find(params[:note_id])` code

Comment: I also tried `@note = params[:note_id]` and it's nil in the create.

Comment: Where is it getting :note_id in the "new" method?

Comment: #Bubbles I appreciate the help - but it's not working for me.

Comment: I assumed you had nested resources that had attachments within notes, but apparently not. Are you confident that "@note" isn't null in the "new" method?

Comment: In the Notes show page I use `        <%= link_to 'New Attachment', new_attachment_path(:note_id => @note.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>`  Then in the Attachments form, I use `                            <% if @note != nil %>
                                <%= f.hidden_field :note_id, :value => @note %>` that makes the association

Comment: Ah. Yes, that makes sense, I didn't pay enough attention to how you described your resources. I updated the answer so it just looks for an id, it shouldn't fail if it is not present. The code as presented still make not quite work though - you have to make sure that if @note is present, the form you return in "new" includes it as a parameter (you may have already done this, I just figured I'd give you a warning in case you hadn't).

Comment: That's what I'm missing - is setting `@note` again in the new attachment form - I think - I'll give it a try and let you know - thanks!

Comment: #Bubbles I tried adding this to my Attachment form `    <%= f.submit 'Save Attachment', params(:note_id => @note.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>` but it didn't work.

Comment: In this case, "@note" is the id - you set it to params[:note_id], so there's no need to add ".id" after it. It's a bit confusing, I'd consider calling it "@note_id" instead.

Comment: Actually, what I just said is relevant, but I don't know if it's sufficient. I'm going to update my answer to reflect how to modify the form.

Comment: I think you need to modify the url on the form, not the submit button. In the form, you'll have to add something like ":url => attachment_path(@attachment, :note_id => @note)". There's a decent chance that precise code won't work though, you'll have to play around  - I can't say for sure without actually working on the project.